# text-overflow in one column in bootstrap-table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-table

My problem is that when adding text-overflow in one column, I lose all the formatting of other columns

```
<table id="table"  data-show-header="false" >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-formatter="check"></th>
          <th data-field="fav" data-formatter="formatoFav" ></th>
          <th data-field="nombre" class="col-md-2"></th>
          <th data-field="asunto" class="col-md-10 abbreviation"></th>
          <th data-field="hora" data-formatter="formatoHora" data-align="right"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

This is the result without css

[image]

And this with CSS

[image]

```
.table  {
   table-layout:fixed;
 }

 .table td.abbreviation{
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Comment: can you create a demo?

Answer (score 2):

Overflow requires a fixed width (or height if needed) to work properly as yo u can see in the overflow documentation. If you dont set width and height on the div you want to overflow, it will break as hidden when overflow parent element (this causes your issue).

**EDITED: better example according to post**

See the example below:

```css
div.foo{background:#000; width:250px;}
div.foc{width:200px; border:1px solid white;}
div.fo1{overflow:hidden; background:#A44;}
div.fo2{width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="foc">
<div class="fo1">
  <span>lalalalaauoshdoajhsdaodshdaojshdaosdhaosldhaoshdasdhaslkdnalsjdnljdalfblaskdfblsakdfbalkfbakldsbfkladsfblkadfbkladfbakldfbakldsbfaksbfkasfbalkdfbksdbfksadjbfkjadsbfkldfblaksdbfkladsbfkladsfbakdsfbdskjbfkbadskfbasldkfbjsadklfbakjdsbfjksad</span>
</div>
<div class="fo2">
  <span> auoshdoajhsdaodshdaojshdaosdhaosldhaoshdasdhaslkdnalsjdnljdalfblaskdfblsakdfbalkfbakldsbfkladsfblkadfbkladfbakldfbakldsbfaksbfkasfbalkdfbksdbfksadjbfkjadsbfkldfblaksdbfkladsbfkladsfbakdsfbdskjbfkbadskfbasldkfbjsadklfbakjdsbfjksad
    </span>
  
 </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Try to delete width:200px of div.foc and see what happer.

Hope it helps,
Cheers! =)